# How to get gps data from mavic 2 using DJI SDK for Windows?

Tags: c#, uwp, gps, dji-sdk

I use windows sdk.
I'm trying to get gps data using the method:

```
var flightControllerHandler = _djiManagerInstance.ComponentManager.GetFlightControllerHandler(ProductIndex, ComponentIndex);
flightControllerHandler.AircraftLocationChanged -= QuadcopterOnAircraftLocationChanged;
```

```
private void QuadcopterOnAircraftLocationChanged(object sender, LocationCoordinate2D? value)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{System.DateTime.Now} LocationCoordinate2D (latitude, longitude) {value.Value.latitude} {value.Value.longitude}"); 
}
```

As a result, I get incomprehensible values in response:

```
12/7/2019 12:26:28 PM LocationCoordinate2D (latitude, longitude) -2.3595119079203E-11 ,-1.12286496566529E-11
12/7/2019 12:26:28 PM LocationCoordinate2D (latitude, longitude) -1.14848682613655E-11 ,2.82582976953522E-11
12/7/2019 12:26:28 PM LocationCoordinate2D (latitude, longitude) 7.99402048749395E-12 ,1.48245993485702E-11
12/7/2019 12:26:28 PM LocationCoordinate2D (latitude, longitude) 2.68203361390684E-11 ,-5.64203826991632E-13
12/7/2019 12:26:28 PM LocationCoordinate2D (latitude, longitude) 2.61363893300918E-11 ,-7.92238385763886E-12
```

Can I somehow convert this data into GPS coordinates or get real GPS coordinates?

Comment: I know GPS very well.  Those values look like clock adjustments.  It looks like the application is extracting the wrong values out of the GPS NAV (navigation) Data.  GPS sends NAV data along with the time and the program is taking the wrong number from the NAV.  Why are you subtracting values?  "-=".  The results are the difference between two values.  GPS is very accurate (less than 1 meter).  So the results is the difference between two very accurate numbers.

Comment: Each line splite by space and get a array from the array you can convert to your format

Comment: I updated the question. Added a code to a method that receives data from DJI Windows SDK. I do not carry out any manipulations with this print as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe the question expired a bit, but just in case someone bumps into this in the future like I did.

The results in the LocationCoordinate2D are the Earth's latitude/longitude in the Geographic coordinate system: [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system). You get them as doubles and in [degrees] unit.

If you are running the simulator without specifying the starting location, you start from 0,0 and not moving the drone will result in noise output like the one you show.

Knowing this, you should be able to convert it to whatever format you need.

Comment: Thank you, we noticed that the drone always starts at 0,0.
How can we convert the obtained values into gps coordinates?

Comment: That's what I'm discovering at the moment, as I've been playing around with the simulator up till now. It should be a matter of getting the home location coordinates somehow, not sure how to extract that yet. But if that is known it's just adding them together. If I find out how, I'll let you know here.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that if you are running a simulator, you need to set the starting location, and that will be used. It is set in the simulator init settings.
If you are physically flying the aircraft, you have 2 cases. If the drone sees enough GPS satellites, it sets the home location automatically based on that. If the signal is not good, you can use the SetHomeLocationUsingAircraftCurrentLocationAsync or SetHomeLocationAsync to set the starting location.
Hope this is helpful!

Comment: After that, the format of the received coordinates will change?

Comment: No, it still shows the same, latitudes and longitudes in degrees. You can convert it to whatever format you need. See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion